# Angular 7 CoreUI : use router for branch URL image link

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-template, core-ui

In the app-header component of [the coreui admin](https://coreui.io/demo/#) template the href attribute of the `<a>` is "" which gives localhost:xxxx that creates a navigation to the root.

I'd like to avoid the full page refresh by using a routerLink that redirects to my root page that I've decided (e.g. the dashboard).

Can I do it ? It seems this template doesn't accept any routing.

The component generates this HTML :

```
<header class="app-header navbar">
   <button appsidebartoggler="" class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" ng-reflect-breakpoint=""><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href=""> <!-- Here is the href I'd like to altered -->
       <img class="navbar-brand-full" src="assets/img/brand/logo-white.png" alt="CoreUI Logo" width="auto" height="auto">
   </a>
    ...
</header>
```

In the default-layout.component.html I'm doing this :

```
<app-header [fixed]="true"
            [navbarBrandFull]="{src: 'assets/img/brand/logo-white.png', alt: 'CoreUI Logo'}"
            [sidebarToggler]="'lg'"
            [asideMenuToggler]="'lg'">
```

Of course I can altered the href like this :

```
<app-header [fixed]="true"
            [navbarBrandFull]="{src: 'assets/img/brand/logo-white.png', alt: 'CoreUI Logo'}"
            [sidebarToggler]="'lg'"
            [asideMenuToggler]="'lg'"
            [navbarBrandHref]="'/dashboard'">
```

But when clicking on the link it reloads completely the page. I'd like the same effect result (more user friendly and much faster as not full reload) than does the menu navigation due to routerLink which give something like :

```
<a routerlinkactive="active" class="active nav-link" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-router-link="/dashboard" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active" href="/dashboard">
   <i class="nav-icon icon-speedometer"></i> Dashboard
   <span class="badge badge-info" ng-reflect-ng-class="badge badge-info">NEW</span>
</a>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

update `@coreui/angular` to `^2.4.5`
and use `navbarBrandRouterLink` instead of `navbarBrandHref`

Answer (score 0):

Try use routerLink instead href: 
Example

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the component I'm using is generating the HTML tag "A", I don't have access to the code. I can only send inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use click function in `<a>` as follows

```
<a class="navbar-brand" (click)="navigate('/dashboard',$event)"></a>
```

and handle the click function in your ts as follows

```
navigate(link, e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.router.navigate([link]);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the component I'm using is generating the HTML tag "A", I don't have access to the code. I can only send inputs.

Comment: you can get url link in  @Input() navbarBrandHref, and pass it in (click)="navigate(navbarBrandHref, $event)"